# i receive an error saying "no operator matches these operands" for the "<<" signs

Tags: c++

I am copying this directly from a textbook.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string myHello = "This is Chapter 3 already?"; 

    cout << myHello << endl; //this part is not working

    return 0;
}
```

Why isn't this code working?

I have tried looking through the book for solutions but no solution is provided or available.

Comment: You haven't included the appropriate header for [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string).

Comment: And put one in the "burn this book" column if that indeed came from a bonafide class text. It *may* be a typo, so check the online eratta before stoking up the BBQ.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about debugging and will have no use for future visitors.

Answer (score 7):

You need to `#include <string>` and then that'll work, do it above the `using namespace` command, if you got rid of the namespace command you'd need to do `std::string myhello;`

[`#include <string>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/string)

Comment: Please check the preview and click the formatting button. Please do not link to cplusplus.com; the quality is poor.

Comment: Did you downvote it for that?

Comment: @JohnPurdy Thanks! I tried LaTeX `$<$` but it didn't work

Comment: Yes, I downvoted. I can revert the downvote if it's fixed. See the help link or hover over the buttons to see what they do. (It's the one marked `{}`.)

Comment: NM. Taken care of. No worries.

Comment: @Potatoswatter bad as that is, I use c++.com without problem, their tutorials suck but it was updated with C++11 stuff, the reference is complete and a good starting point, what do you suggest?

Comment: +1 for using cplusplus.com

Comment: And for the record, I much-prefer cppreference.com. Its maintained by people that are one step away from their mom's basement because all they do is live and breathe C++. It is *easily* closer to the standard than any other site I've used, including cplusplus.com, and I believe it to be  the best online resource for the language you'll find. (My opinion, not that it matters much).

Comment: @NeilKirk thanks, I've used them for years, their tutorials are poor, but it is a good quick reference, I have all the editions of "The C++ programming language" a print out of the specification, the design and evolution of C++, and the C++ reference manual at my desk XD I rarely need it, but that said PotatoSwatter if there is a better source, I am all ears.

Comment: @WhozCraig you are right that is much better.... thanks for telling me :) I shall bookmark that!

Comment: @Potatoswatter better? I'm a bit upset about getting a -2 for a totally correct answer..... I .... perhaps I should read more about rep but it seems quite .... petty, please undo it?

Comment: @AlecTeal There are no downvotes on this that I see.

Comment: @WhozCraig sorry the "-2" has gone now, thanks for that website again btw, that is much nicer and detailed.

Comment: @WhozCraig professional C++ development takes people pretty far from basements..

Comment: @Cubbi true that, but these guys are just nuts. I can't speak highly enough for the contributions to that site, esp from some of the very people on this site (many, in fact). They changed the way I thought of the language, and I've been doing this for 23 years. Every time I think I know enough about something, they always bring more.

Comment: ANOTHER downvote!? That's 4 now with no explanation!